# Create a link to Search Results with a dynamic Query Variable (ie: Site Title)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, markup

I want to create a link to the search results page with the current SiteTitle in the URL.
For example:

```
http://mysitecollection/SearchResults.aspx#k=thisSiteTitle
```

What is the SP Designer markup?
For example:

```
<a href="~sitecollection/SearchResults.aspx#k=<!--SPM<thisSiteTitle/>-->">Link to Search Results</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript:

```
<a onclick="javascript: location.href = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/SearchResults.aspx?k=' + _spPageContextInfo.webTitle">Link to Search Results</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I was looking for a non-JavaScript way of doing it. Either in ASP or XML.